# Install Trans-Proteomic Pipeline (TPP) 4.6.1 on Linux Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

I have some problem installing TPP software on my Linux environment (Redhat). The error message is showed as below:

```
perl -c  -I  ../../build/RedHat-x86_64 ../../build/RedHat-x86_64/tpp_gui.pl
Can't locate IO/Compress/Zip.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ../../build/RedHat-x86_64 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ../../build/RedHat-x86_64/tpp_gui.pl line 16.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../../build/RedHat-x86_64/tpp_gui.pl line 16.
make[1]: *** [../../build/RedHat-x86_64/tpp_gui.pl] Error 2
make[1]: *** Deleting file `../../build/RedHat-x86_64/tpp_gui.pl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/TPP-4.6.1/trans_proteomic_pipeline/src/perl_paths'
make: *** [perl_paths] Error 2
```

Can somebody help me out with this problem? I have an urge to install and run TPP now.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you are missing the Perl module IO::Compress::Zip in your system, you should firstly install that Perl module and then have another try

Comment: I have typed command perl -v and it shows perl v5.8.8 as the current installed version.

Comment: Perl installed doesn't mean the needed Perl module IO::Compress::Zip has been installed, you can refer to this link on how to install a Perl module: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=128077

Comment: Bravo! This is exactly where the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docker machine we recently create here: https://github.com/BioDocker/TPP-4.8.0 , we are maintaining those containers then feel free to contact the team.

Regards

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: The biodocker allow you to install only a docker machine of TPP and you can use it like a normal commandline installation